# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'httplib2' - using BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator in Airflow

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I'm trying to create an airflow (1.10.9) pipline, I'm using the [puckel](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) docker image (I'm working with the local [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml) every thing works well until I tried to import the [BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.9/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_to_gcs/index.html?highlight=airflow%20contrib%20operators%20bigquery_to_gcs#module-airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_to_gcs)

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_to_gcs import BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator
```

I get this exception :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 243, in process_file m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source module = _load(spec)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/coo_dag.py", line 6, in <module> from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_to_gcs import BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_to_gcs.py", line 20, in <module> from airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook import BigQueryHook
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 34, in <module> from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcp_api_base_hook import GoogleCloudBaseHook
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_api_base_hook.py", line 25, in <module> import httplib2
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'httplib2'
```

I tried to install the pakage **apache-airflow[gcp]==1.10.9** either manuelly (by accessing the the aiflow webserver machine and running pip install) or by mounting a file (requirements.txt ) as a volume but it doesn't work

 (when I mount the file as volume, the webserver machine doesn't start It cannot install the requirments.
here is the docker-compose.yml that I'm using :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"

    webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=y
            - EXECUTOR=Local
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            # - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3
```

and here is the content of the file requirements.txt :

```
apache-airflow[gcp]==1.10.9
```

Comment: If you find my answer helpful for your question, please consider to accept/upvote it as per [stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

To mount the requirements.txt file as a volume inside the container, the file has to be in the same directory as the docker-compose.yml file for the relative path to work. Consider correcting the indentation of the mounted volumes in the yml file as shown below.

```
volumes:
    - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
    - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
```

I have also added some more dependencies to requirements.txt which are required for the BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator() task to work.

Below is the contents of **requirements.txt**

```
pandas==0.25.3
pandas-gbq==0.14.1
apache-airflow[gcp]==1.10.9
```

In case your previous Airflow instance is already running, consider running a **sudo docker-compose stop** first before you compose again (**sudo docker-compose up**) .
Also, the bigquery_default connection in Airflow should be edited to add the correct GCP project_id and service account json key.